# Hi-res Icon app Suspended possible to restore

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

We found an issue in the following area(s): Hi-res Icon: Your app icon appears to contain images or words you may not have permission to use.

App status: Suspended Your app has been suspended and removed due to this policy issue.

is it possible to restore it???
[image]

Comment: Replace the assets in question?

Comment: means?
playstore only giving to interact with Policy status page all other are disbled